# Can I create a multiuse token with Stripe payment gateway in React Native?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payment gateway (using tipsi-stripe) for payment in React Native. Can I create a token that is created once for a particular credit or debit card, and that token is then stored permanently in the database and used in every payment that is done with that card?

I only found from search that tokens cannot be stored or used more than once with Stripe. Is it possible to create a token for multiuse with Stripe?

Comment: We can create that because stripe has provided a feature to store the credit or debit cards using the token. You can read more [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens) and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card)

Comment: Thanks for reply.I also read from there. There is also describes that tokens can not reused.

Comment: [Here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/reusing-cards) they didn't mention anything.